# How to use refresh indicator inside a futurebuilder in flutter

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I want to use refresh indication in flutter futurebuilder. I looked for the solutuion but but not worked in my case.
I have provided my code below.
I found a solution where they suggested to use the stack but that solutiion not worked either.

```
column(children:[
...
  const Heading("New Workers !"),
                FutureBuilder(
                  future: SupervisorServices.getWorkersList(),
                  builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
                    var data = snapshot.data;
                    if (snapshot.hasData) {
                      return RefreshIndicator(
                        onRefresh: () {
                          return SupervisorServices.getWorkersList();
                        },
                        child: ListView.builder(
                          itemCount: data.length,
                          shrinkWrap: true,
                          physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                            return Card(
                              child: ListTile(
                                leading: const SizedBox(
                                  height: double.infinity,
                                  child: Icon(
                                    FeatherIcons.user,
                                  ),
                                ),
                               //...   
                                ),
                              ),
                            );
                          },
                        ),
                      );
                    } 
...//rest code
                  },
                ),
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Try add async

```
onRefresh: () async{
return SupervisorServices.getWorkersList();
},
```